# CodeIgniter 3 code does not add data to database into 2 different tables (user_info & phone_info)

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-query-builder

The problem is when I entered a new name no data is added. A similar thing happen when I entered an already existing name. Still, no data is added to the database. I am still new to CodeIgniter and not entirely sure my query builder inside the model is correct or not.

In the Model, I check if the name already exists insert data only into the `phone_info` table. IF name does not exist I insert data into `user_info` and `phone_info`.

**Controller:**

```
public function addData()
{
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $contact_num = $this->input->post('contact_num');
    if($name == '') {
        $result['message'] = "Please enter contact name";
    } elseif($contact_num == '') {
        $result['message'] = "Please enter contact number";
    } else {
        $result['message'] = "";
        $data = array(
            'name' => $name,
            'contact_num' => $contact_num
        );
        $this->m->addData($data);
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

**Model:**

```
public function addData($data)
{
    if(mysqli_num_rows($data['name']) > 0) {
        $user = $this->db->get_where('user_info', array('name' => $data['name']))->result_array();
        $user_id = $user['id'];
        $phone_info = array(
            'contact_num' => $data['contact_num'],
            'user_id' => $user_id
        );
        $this->db->insert('phone_info',$phone_info);
    } else {
        $user_info = array(
            'name' => $data['name']
        );
        $this->db->insert('user_info', $user_info);
        $user = $this->db->get_where('user_info', array('name' => $data['name']))->result_array();
        $user_id = $user['id'];
        $phone_info = array(
            'contact_num' => $data['contact_num'],
            'user_id' => $user_id
        );
        $this->db->insert('phone_info', $phone_info);
    }
}
```

**DB-Table user_info:**
[image: user_info table]

**DB-Table phone_info:**
[image: phone_info table]

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of your code. Post actual code.
Refer to [Formatting tips](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: The code looks almost correct. But I am not sure if `mysqli_num_rows($data['name']) > 0` works as you'd expect. Can you asure that `$this->m->addData($data);` is called?

Answer (score 0):

Extend and change your **model** to this:

```
public function findByTitle($name)
{
    $this->db->where('name', $name);
    return $this->result();
}

public function addData($data)
{
    if(count($this->findByTitle($data['name'])) > 0) {
        //.. your code
    } else {
        //.. your code
    }
}
```

---

**Explanation:**

This:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($data['name']) > 0)
```

..is not working to find database entries by name. To do this you can use codeigniters built in model functions and benefit from the MVC Pattern features, that CodeIgniter comes with.

I wrapped the actual `findByName` in a function so you can adapt this to other logic and use it elswehere later on. This function uses the `query()` method.

Read more about [CodeIgniters Model Queries](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=where#selecting-data) in the [documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/index.html).

---

*Sidenote:* `mysqli_num_rows` is used to iterate find results recieved by `mysqli_query`. This is very basic sql querying and you do not need that in a MVC-Framework like CodeIgniter. If you every appear to need write a manual sql-query, even then you should use CodeIgniters RawQuery methods.